# Shader material not displayed in safari 14.2

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, webgl, ios14

There is a shader that uses Perlin noise to create a wave effect. But on safari 14.2, material using this shader is simply not displayed. Is there a way to make it work on newer iOS versions? [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/06-final-displacement-trg1k?from-embed=&file=/src/gl/glsl/vertex.glsl)

Comment: Any error messages?

Comment: nothing, the shader compiles fine and everything works on IOS <14

Comment: Do you mean it's not displayed in Safari 14.2 or on iOS 14.2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into very similar issues. The solution is fairly simple. Noise function do need high precision floats.

```
precision highp float;
```

instead of

```
precision mediump float;
```

does the trick*. Tried it in your example and it does work, needed to adjust the `noiseAmp` as highp noise seems to be a bit harsher than the mediump noise.